# Date filteration in Postgre SQL

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to get the row which has the date is equal to 2017-01-12. The date has field type timestamp without time zone. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE date = 2017-01-12;
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: [Date/Time Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE date = '2017-01-12';
```

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, try an explicit cast:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabl 
WHERE date = DATE '2017-01-12';
```